# Right way to dynamically create qml windows

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm working on a Qt application and I need to create windows dynamically. Each window consists of QObject-based c++ backend and qml-based interface. Each window needs to be connected to the bunch of signals emitted by core classes.
Current solution is to derive window from `QQuickView`, connect signals to it and load qml using `setSource()`. Is it a right way or there is a better way?
Is it better to use one `QQmlEngine` for all windows (and use this engine as parent for every window) or create new engine for each new window?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically ? Will you have a variable list of QObjects and want one window for each ?

Comment: @GrecKo yes, a list of QObjects with one window (using the same qml file) for each QObject in list. And core classes need to be able to add and/or remove objects (and windows) in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would expose a [c++ model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#exposing-c-data-models-to-qml) to the QML code.
Since this model would be dynamic (elements can be added or removed), I'd use a `QAbstractItemModel` derived model that can inform the views that some elements are added/removed. Using something else like a `QList<QObject*>` would mean that you'd have to tell the view that the entire model should be reloaded after each change.

Instead of implementing the model from scratch, you could use a class like [`QQmlObjectListModel` from Qt QML Tricks](http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models), it exposes a QList-like API from c++ but is a `QAbstractItemModel` exposing the `QObject` properties as roles under the scene.

Another solution that you could use if you don't want to use QObjects is [benlau's `QSyncable`](https://github.com/benlau/qsyncable) (I've actually used this in a similar situation to yours, where I expose my screens in a model and instantiate a `Window` displaying a taskbar for each).

Then, I'd use a `QQmlApplicationEngine` and expose the model to it with `setContextProperty`. A `QQuickView` is already a window, so I don't think you want to use that, better to manage your windows manually in the QML code.

Then in your QML code, use an [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html) as your root object, set your model, and use `Window` as its delegate :

```
Instantiator {
    model: yourModel
    Window {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this approach support different types of windows? And I also need the window sets be savable and loadable to save and restore program sessions, how can I do it using this approach?

Comment: I fear this make your question too broad. There is a lot of way to save and load the windows states: with settings, a local db, some custom serialization, ... As for supporting different types of windows, it can means a lot of things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after some research and some prototyping I've came to conclusion that this approach is indeed the best for the situation I've described. Unfortunately QML windows does not fit really good with the whole concept of the application so I think I will switch back to widgets in my software. But thank you again for the answer.